# Passengers: Why is the Earth presented as an overpriced planet?

Tags: passengers

In the Passengers movie, Earth is positioned/presented as an "overpriced" planet:

> Earth is a PROSPEROUS planet, the cradle of civilization.
>   But for many, it's also overpopulated, OVERPRICED, overrated.

Travelling to Avalon is also expensive, and only for riches and technical persons. There is no sign of migrants...

- Why did the creators decide to make the Earth an overpriced planet?
- Did they base this decision on any theoretical background?

Comment: Are you asking for real-world possibilities? Or for creators' commentary on their choices? The former is off-topic on this site.

Comment: I prefer both, and essipecially the one which you want to answer.

Comment: *"...riches and technical persons."* - Not so. There were 5000 **migrants/homesteaders/colonists** on board (excluding crew) and there were different levels of passenger status.

Comment: I got the impression that people migrating to the colony were basically indentured servants. Aurora, the journalist who came from a rich family, had money, but most weren't at that level.

Comment: The trip to Avalon isn't merely for the wealthy and well-trained. It would appear that (within reason), anyone can go there. Our hero was given a discount on his tariff (the percentage of his salary that he had to pay to the Homestead Corporation) *because* he had a useful skill.

Answer (score 9):

The description of Earth appears in promotional material from the company which built the *Avalon*. It is obviously trying to appeal to dissatisfaction with life on Earth, so it implies Earth is too crowded and too expensive.

The company believes these claims will motivate the colonists. We do not know whether they are true in some sort of absolute sense, and for the purposes of the film it doesn't matter.